# Convert object to string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, object, out-of-memory, tostring

I have variable in pandas dataframe with values as below

```
print (df.xx)

1          5679558
2        (714) 254
3                0
4         00000000
5        000000000
6      00000000000
7        000000001
8        000000002
9        000000003
10       000000004
11       000000005

print (df.dtypes)
xx         object
```

I am like below in order to convert this as num

```
try:
    print df.xx.apply(str).astype(int)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

I did try like this

```
tin.tin = tin.tin.to_string().astype(int)
```

But this giving me `MemoryError`, as I have 3M rows.

Can some body help me in stripping special chars and converting as int64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if the string [`isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) and then use the boolean mask to convert those rows only in a vectorised manner and use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html#pandas.to_numeric) with param `errors='coerce'`:

```
In [88]:
df.loc[df['xxx'].str.isdigit(), 'xxx'] = pd.to_numeric(df['xxx'], errors='coerce')
df

Out[88]:
            xxx
0   5.67956e+06
1     (714) 254
2             0
3             0
4             0
5             0
6             1
7             2
8             3
9             4
10            5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could split your huge dataframe into chunks, for example this method can do it where you can decide what is the chunk size:

```
def splitDataFrameIntoSmaller(df, chunkSize = 10000): 
    listOfDf = list()
    numberChunks = len(df) // chunkSize + 1
    for i in range(numberChunks):
        listOfDf.append(df[i*chunkSize:(i+1)*chunkSize])
    return listOfDf
```

After you have chunks, you can apply your function on each chunk separately.